# DirectX with Windows 7 and Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, directx-11

I am developing an application with DirectX11 on Windows 7 environment with DirectX SDK (June 2010). Windows 8 and 8.1 come with Windows SDK (which includes DirectX SDK). I found out that some of the header files from DirectX SDK are not included in Windows SDK. (D3DX11Core.h, D3DX11.h, etc)

My questions are:

- Will my application run on Windows 8 & 8.1 environment?
- Backward compatibility on Windows 8 and 8.1 for DirectX 11 or DirectX 10
- What if my application uses deprecated header file (eg D3DX11.h), will it work on windows 8

This is my current working envrionment

- OS = Windows 7
- DirectX = DirectX SDK (June 2010)
- DirectX 11 with Direct3D 11
- Windows Kits (Installed with Visual Studio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D3DX is deprecated since the inclusion of DirectX in the Windows SDK done first with the Windows kits 8 shipped with VS2012.

An application built with the June 2010 SDK and D3DX will of course work on all windows with the proper redist.

Still, the DirectX June 2010 sdk is deprecated for years, you miss some revised API that are useful to write Windows Apps for the Metro interface and mixing the two will give you conflicts and a strong headache.

Comment: Hi galop1n, Thanks for the answer. What if my application uses deprecated header file (eg D3DX11.h), will it work on windows 8

Answer (score 0):

Direct3D 11 Win32 desktop applications will run on Windows 8.x assuming you install the required Visual C++ REDIST. If you are using the legacy components in the DirectX SDK such as D3DX, D3DCompiler #43, XAudio 2.7, XInput 1.3, or XACT you need to also run the DirectX End-User Runtime REDIST. Note that there are some known issues with the DirectX REDIST which have been addressed after the DXSDK (June 2010) release. See this blog [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2011/04/19/dxsetup-update.aspx).

If you want to build with VS 2012/2013 and the legacy DirectX SDK, you can. You just need to reverse the include/lib paths order per the instructions non [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx).

Also, if you are using D3DX11 there are lots of [options](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/08/21/living-without-d3dx.aspx) to replacing it without picking up additional DLL dependencies.